# Zur Wortart und Groß- und Kleinschreibung von "anderer"

Tags: capitalization

Ich habe mich gefragt, ob in dem folgenden Satz Groß- oder Kleinschreibung von "anderer" gilt:

> Ich traf Tom und **die anderen**.

In [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/anderer) und [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/andere) wird "anderer" als Indefinitpronomen angegeben, während auf Seite 381 des Dudenband 4 von einem Adjektiv die Rede ist.
Substantiviert müsste das Zählwort "anderer" nach den Rechtschreibregeln im Dudenband 9 Seite 432 und auf der [Webseite(62)](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D72) groß geschrieben werden. Substantivierte Zählwörter schreibe man groß, sagen sie dort.
Es ist einleuchtend, dass bei Auslassung des Substantivs nach [§73](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D72) "anderer" kleingeschrieben wird, es ist dann aber auch kein Substantiv. [§77](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D77) verwirrt aber: Wie ist "Der substantivische Charakter kann hervorgehoben werden" zu verstehen? Kann "anderer" also ein Substantiv sein, dessen Charakter wir bloß nicht hervorheben, weshalb es dennoch kleingeschreiben wird? Wie ich es momentan verstehe: Schreiben wir "andere" groß, nutzen wir es als Substantiv und betonen es damit besonders ("die Anderen"), schreiben wir es klein, wenden wir den wie es Duden nennt "attributiv-elliptischen" Gebrauch an.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Grund für die Unsicherheit

Wie Tofro schon gesagt hat, rührt die Unsicherheit wohl daher, dass das Wort *andere* in einigen Fällen klein geschrieben wird, wo man typische Adjektive gross schreibt:

- Nach Artikel und ohne Rückverweis auf vorangehendes Substantiv: *die anderen* (im Gegensatz zu: *die Grossen)*
- Nach Pronomen: *jemand anderes* (im Gegensatz zu: *jemand Grosses)*

Demgegenüber stehen Fälle, wo das Wort *andere* gross geschrieben wird (wie ein typisches Adjektiv in ähnlichen Fällen):

- der Andere (wie: *der Fremde)*

In solchen Fällen kann man wohl von einer besonders ausdrücklichen Verdinglichung sprechen, die eine Grossschreibung rechtfertigt (obwohl die Wörter weiterhin wie Adjektive deklinieren, vgl. starke Deklination von *ein Ander**er**, ein Fremd**er**).*

### Wortart von *andere*

Offensichtlich ist die Wortartzuteilung von *andere* nicht ganz klar – wie bereits in der Frage genannt, kann es als Adjektiv (Dudengrammatik) oder als Pronomen analysiert werden (Wiktionary). Interessanter als bloss anzugeben, welche Quellen welche Analyse bevorzugen, ist die Frage nach den Gründen für die eine oder andere Analyse.

In der Dudengrammatik wird das Wort *andere* zu den unbestimmten bzw. indefiniten Zahladjektiven gezählt. Für diese Analyse gibt es zwei Gründe:

1. Die Deklination von *andere* ist adjektivisch.
2. Im Gegensatz zu gewöhnlichen Adjektiven schwankt ein auf *andere* folgendes Adjektiv zwischen starker und schwacher Deklination.

#### Adjektivische Deklination

Adjektivische Deklination bedeutet, dass das Wort *andere* im Gegensatz zu einem Substantiv nicht nur nach Kasus und Numerus, sondern auch nach Genus und Definitheit dekliniert:

- Genus: *ander**e** Frau, ander**er** Mann, ander**es** Kind* (wie: *gut**e** Frau, gut**er** Mann, gut**es** Kind)*
- Definitheit: Starke Deklination in *ander**es** Glück/mit ander**em** Glück* vs. schwache Deklination in *dieses ander**e** Glück/mit diesem ander**en** Glück* (wie: *gut**es** Glück/mit gut**em** Glück* vs. *dieses gut**e** Glück/mit diesem gut**en** Glück)*

In Bezug auf die eigene Deklination verhält sich das Wort *andere* also wie ein Adjektiv.

#### Schwankende Deklination eines folgenden Adjektivs

Das Schwanken des auf *andere* folgenden Adjektivs zwischen starker und schwacher Deklination bedeutet, dass ein folgendes Adjektiv teils – wie nach einem typischen Adjektiv – stark, teils – wie nach Artikelwörtern – schwach dekliniert wird.

Schwache Deklination:

- unter anderem klein**en** Privatbesitz (wie: *unter diesem klein**en** Privatbesitz,* nicht wie: *unter unbedeutendem klein**em** Privatbesitz)*
- anderm harmlos**en** Getier (wie: *diesem harmlos**en** Getier,* nicht wie: *freundlichem harmlos**em** Getier)*

Starke Deklination:

- anderes gedruckt**es** Material (wie: *gutes gedruckt**es** Material,* nicht wie: *dieses gedruckt**e** Material)*
- in Gestalt anderer alt**er** Damen (wie: *in Gestalt guter alt**er** Damen,* nicht wie: *in Gestalt dieser alt**en** Damen)*

Gemäss diesem Kriterium weicht *andere* von typischen Adjektiven ab. Es gesellt sich zu einer bestimmten Gruppe von Wörtern wie *alle, keine, sämtliche* usw., nach denen die Adjektive ebenfalls mit schwankender Deklination auftreten können.

Das Kriterium der schwankenden Deklination ist allerdings kein besonders solider Grund. Schliesslich ist auch bei typischen Adjektiven nicht ausgeschlossen, dass ein folgendes Adjektiv eine schwache Deklination aufweist, beispielsweise: *unter unbedeutendem klein**en** Privatbesitz* statt: *unter unbedeutendem klein**em** Privatbesitz.* Es handelt sich um eine relativ obskure Provinz der deutschen Grammatik, wo auch unter Muttersprachlern nicht immer Einigkeit besteht.

#### Indefinites Zahladjektiv vs. Indefinitpronomen

Ich habe auf die Schnelle in der Dudengrammatik keine Abgrenzung zwischen unbestimmten Zahladjektiven und Indefinitpronmen gefunden. Bezeichnenderweise tauchen einige Wörter in beiden Gruppen auf *(alle, etliche, manche, mehrere, sämtliche),* einige nur bei den unbestimmten Zahladjektiven *(andere, beide, einige, et-/irgend-/welche, folgende, solche, viele, wenige)* und wieder andere nur bei den Indefinitpronomen *(ein bisschen/wenig/paar, einer, etwas, jeder/-mann/jedweder, jeglicher, jemand, niemand, kein, man, meinesgleichen, nichts, wer, was).* Dies spricht dafür, dass ein klares Abgenzungskriterium fehlt – zumindest in der Dudengrammatik. Ein mögliches Abgrenzungskriterium wäre folgendes:

3. Vor (attributivem) *andere* können Artikelwörter auftreten.

Dies äussert sich etwa wie folgt:

- *andere Beispiele/**die anderen** Beispiele/**diese anderen** Beispiele* (wie: *viele Beispiele/**die vielen** Beispiele/**diese vielen** Beispiele,* nicht wie: *keine Beispiele/**★die keinen** Beispiele/**★diese keinen** Beispiele)*

In dieser Hinsicht würde *andere* zur gleichen Gruppe gehören wie *sämtliche, eine, beide, viele, wenige,* aber zu einer anderen Gruppe als *alle, einige, et-/irgend-/welche, keine, jede.* Man könnte dann also erstere als indefinite Zahladjektive zählen, letztere als Indefinitpronomen.

Bei Wörter wie *ein bisschen/wenig/paar, etwas, jedermann, jemand, niemand, man, meinesgleichen, nichts* ist die Zuordnung zu den Indefinitpronomen übrigens klarer, denn sie haben keine (oder nur rudimentäre) Adjektivdeklination, und viele können auch nicht attributiv auftreten.

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese Antwort und das Eingehen auf die Wortart und die Grüne dafür. Ich bin mir sicher, zukünftig werden viele Leute auf diesen Beitrag stoßen und ihnen wird durch die Antworten unter diesem Beitrag sehr geholfen werden.

Answer (score 4):

In

> Ich traf Tom und die anderen

ist "die anderen" ein Indefinitpronomen, das grundsäzlich erst mal klein geschrieben wird - nämlich offensichtlich Toms Clique, die wohl insgesamt namentlich bekannt ist - ds ist dann meiner Meinung nach nichtmal eine Auslassung, denn es ist klar, wer gemeint ist (witzigerweise ist das Indefinitpronomen hier ziemlich "definit verwendet").

Dann gibt es noch den adjektivischen Gebrauch, der ist hier erstmal nicht interessant und nur der Vollständigkeit halber:

> Der andere Mann ging über die Straße.

Ich denke, deine Verwirrung stammt daher, dass es auch einen substantivischen Gebrauch gibt, wo "die Anderen" als eigenständige Begrifflichkeit aufgefasst wird - Das beste Beispiel dafür, das mir grade einfällt, ist der Filmtitel

> Das Leben der Anderen

in dem es um Stasi-Überwachung von "den Anderen", nämlich die (substantivierte) Gruppe von (beliebigen, immer verschiedenen) Menschen am anderen Ende der Überwachungsleitung.

Comment: Dann ist "anderer" also ein Indefinitpronomen, das adjektivisch und substantiviert verwendet werden kann? Die adjektivische Nutzung reicht dann dafür, dass Dudenband 4 es "Adjektiv" bezeichnet, nehme ich dann mal an.

Comment: Das ist zumindestens mein Verständnis.

Answer (score 0):

Das zutreffende Beispiel bei D77 (§ 58 E4) lautet *das Andere*, glossiert "eine neue Welt".

Es ist davon auszugehen, dass es Vorgänger berücksichtigt wurden. In der Gegenwartssprache kommt es so gut wie nicht vor.

Siehe Grimm (Deutsches Wörterbuch), wo noch konsequent klein geschrieben wird, über den Wechsel von *zweiter* und *ander* übrigens folgendes zur Paarität:

> ... *wenn ein ebenbild, ein gegenstück von nur als zwein gedachten dingen, ausgedrückt werden soll:*

Damit ist es nunmal nicht indefinit. Das scheint anhand jener Beispiele relevant zu sein

> alsus het ich beseʒʒen
> daʒ ander pardîse.
> *Iw.* 687;

ferner

> du bleibst mein ander ich,
> bis mir der tod das treue herze bricht.
> *Menantes* 1, 178;

usw. Vgl. engl. *my significant other*. Ein ähnlicher Sachverhalt wäre damit bspw. *das Ich*. Für eine kurze Erklärung sollte das vermutlich reichen.

Etymologisch scheint doch einiges mehr auf dem Spiel zu stehen.

Eine nach wie vor bemerkenswerte Parallele liegt so wie so in der Wurzel von *alter, alter ego*. De Vaan zählt dazu unter anderem auf althochdeutsch *elilenti* "foreign country". Vgl. *the otherworld*, bzw. *underworld* "Unterwelt", die eine oder andere paradiesische Glaubensvorstellung, wo die Sonne nicht scheint.